# Use Grails and Less Together

Tags: css, grails, less

I would like to have the following in a Grails **.less** file

```
@product-dark-color: ${dynamicColorService.getCurrentColor()};
```

Is this possible?

To give some background: There is a new project requirement that different users should see different colors on login. The project is using less today with one file containing all the colors, and we would like to change that one file per-user on login (or some other way of accomplishing the same thing).

**Subsequent Edit**

Having looked around a little more, I would like to know if the following is possible:

- Use less.js for client-side processing of less instead of server-side processing with one of the grails less plugins
- Have a `global.css.gsp` file with `<script type="text/less">` and therefore that `global.css.gsp` file can make Controller calls to dynamically get system resources/colors etc.
- Now other `.less` files can include `global.css` to reference the necessary less variables

What I am missing?

Comment: No. `.less` files are pre-compiled when the application is packaged. They aren't processed at run-time.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: However there are two versions of less: server-side and client-side.  What if the client-side version is used?

Comment: I don't think the Groovy Server Pages (GSP) engine will process the `.less` files and thus it wouldn't matter. That's still the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: So then is there a different way to (for example) have a main.gsp that includes a style section with type less that is dynamically created?  Or have a .css.gsp file with less code inside it?